# Is there a TFS check-in policy to prevent check-ins across team projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm having some trouble with some team members accidentally checking in code across (usually unrelated) Team Projects.  I could flog them for not being careful or try to find an easier way to bring this to their attention. We are running TFS 2010 & VS 2010.

Is there a TFS check-in policy to prevent check-ins across team projects?

Answer (score 4):

I'm really disappointed by these responses. TFS is a tool to make developers work better and more efficiently. To blame a developer for being lazy or not paying attention seems like an absolute cope out. What if you hire a new employee that has limited knowledge and simply makes a mistake? Tools should allow us to assist and teach developers on appropriate methods.

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't have this problem if they either check in from the Solution Explorer or from a sub-folder (or individual team project) in the Source Code Explorer.  It sounds like they're being lazy and simply right clicking on `$/` and checking in.

That being said, I haven't seen any out-of-the-box policies for doing this.  However, writing your own using the TFS API is very straightforward.

Jim Lamb's article is probably the best place to start:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx

Comment: I hear you.  The big challenge with check in policies is going to be ensuring the devs install them and keep them up to date.

Comment: Yes, being careful is required; but the cause is not necessarily being lazy. It is too easy to do this by mistake. It's not just checking in from the root. If you have multiple branches open in different instances of Visual Studio, the include/exclude can get mingled among the instances. I'll check out the link.

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2010 check-in policies aren't evaluated for check-ins across multiple projects, so a check-in policy can't do what you want.

However, there is code for a VS addin in the first comment of this bug-report which looks like it does what you want:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/a71ac2f0-dc9c-4c03-a6a3-ab59877c55d8/

Comment: Agree with @benpmorgan tools should not allow users to make dumb mistakes.  After a long day, it's very easy to click the check in button and accidentally checkin files from other projects that are not ready to be checked in - this is a deficiency in the tool.